# SVG defs use relation between different figures Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, svg

We've got a simply code, which works cross-browser:

```
<html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="200" height="100">

    <circle id="circ" cx="120" cy="40" 
    r="30" fill="green"/>

    <rect id="rect" x="10" y="10"
    width="60" height="60" fill="blue">
        <set attributeName="fill-opacity" to="0.5"
        begin="circ.mouseover" end="circ.mouseout"/>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

When I try to use the elements in defs block I'm losing relation between two rectangles in Firefox browser.

```
<html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="200" height="100">
    <defs>
        <circle id="circ" cx="120" cy="40" 
        r="30" fill="green"/>

        <rect id="rect" x="10" y="10"
        width="60" height="60" fill="blue">
            <set attributeName="fill-opacity" to="0.5"
            begin="circ.mouseover" end="circ.mouseout"/>
        </rect>
    </defs>

    <use id="use_circ.rectangles" xlink:href="#circ" />
    <use id="use_rect.rectangles" xlink:href="#rect" />
</svg>
```

I've read something about relation here http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/mouseover-effects-svgs? - actually this words

> "Note that this effect does not work in Firefox Firefox 6 and earlier (I think), which is perhaps the biggest drawback of this method. "

I need to press the button to move(change) another element.
I also tried to make something like this, to set relation effect:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Button</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function turn_right(button, miliSec)
        {
            document.getElementById("circ_left_position").setAttribute('visibility','hidden');

            setTimeout(function() {
                button.parentNode.setAttribute('xlink:href','#rect.right_position');
            }, miliSec);

            document.getElementById("circ_right_position").setAttribute('visibility','visible ');
        }
        function turn_left(button, miliSec)
        {
            document.getElementById("circ_right_position").setAttribute('visibility','hidden ');

            setTimeout(function() {
                button.parentNode.setAttribute('xlink:href','#rect.left_position');
            }, miliSec);

            document.getElementById("circ_left_position").setAttribute('visibility','visible ');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0; border:0">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="200" height="100">

        <defs>
            <g id="rect.left_position" onclick="turn_right(this,500)">
                <rect x="10" y="10" width="60" height="60" fill="blue"/>

                <circle id="circ_left_position" cx="120" cy="40" r="30" fill="green"/>

                <animateTransform id="trigger1" begin="click"
                attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="replace"
                from="0 70 70" to="10 70 70" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" />
            </g>

            <g id="rect.right_position" onclick="turn_left(this,500)">
                <rect x="10" y="10" width="60" height="60" fill="blue" transform="rotate(10 70 70)"/>
                <circle id="circ_right_position" cx="120" cy="40" r="30" fill="green"/>

                <animateTransform id="trigger1" begin="click"
                attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="replace"
                from="0 70 70" to="-10 70 70" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" />
            </g>
        </defs>

        <use id="positions.rectangles" xlink:href="#rect.left_position" />

    </svg>
</body>
```

In Chrome and FF we get different results. Farther, I don't understand difference in browsers. I'm sure, there exist a simple solution.

Comment: SMIL doesn't work very well with `<use>` elements in Firefox I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you tried to use a library such as Snap.svg to animate it instead of the SMIL animations? The support for SMIL animations isn't as good as it should be right now.

Answer (score 0):

A use does not copy the animation this is not expected behavior in SVG 1.1 (this is not a firefox issue)

Smil in SVG 2 will address this.

What you can do is to use scripting to clone each animation and append them to the use tag. Perhaps on a onload event. However I believe this will not work for your specific code set because specify an id.